# Where Google Photos for iOS hide “Assistant” tab?

Tags: google-photos

Google photos for iOS app used to have an Assistant tab with amazing funny things like animations other things.
Now that I’ve got the latest version 5.0 I can’t find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the new creations are hidden inside the Recent Highlights item but it’s very inconvenient as it mixes both plain old photos with creations.
Very bad UI IMHO.